# Rust Ownership and Lifetimes using Combine

Tags: rust

I've read the docs on ownership and lifetimes and I think I understand them but I'm having trouble with a specific bit of code.

I have a struct called `Branch` like this:

```
struct Branch {
    slot: u8,
    yaw: u8,
    pitch: u8,
    length: u8
}
```

I'm using the `combine` library (it's a parser combinator) to parse a string into a Branch. The parsers look like this:

```
let hex_re = Regex:new(r"[0-9a-fA-F]").unwrap();
let hex = || find(&hex_re).map(|s| u8::from_str_radix(s, 16));
let branch = |length: u8| {
    (hex(), hex(), hex())
        .map( |t| (t.0.unwrap(), t.1.unwrap(), t.2.unwrap()) )
        .map( |(slot,yaw,pitch)| Branch { slot, yaw, pitch, length } )
}
```

The parsers are fairly simple, the first `hex` takes a regular-expression which matches a single hexidecimal character and maps it into a u8. The second `branch` maps 3 hex characters into a Branch e.g. 3d2.

The problem arises when I call the parser `branch(1).parse("3d2")`, the compiler reports an error `'length' does not live long enough`. I think I understand this error, if I'm not mistaken it's because `length` goes out of scope when the closure completes and so the `length` variable is deallocated even though it is still being used by the newly created Branch.

So, I tried to get around this by converting `length: u8` to `length: &u8` like so:

```
let branch = |len: &u8| {
    (hex(), hex(), hex())
        .map( |t| (t.0.unwrap(), t.1.unwrap(), t.2.unwrap()) )
        .map( |(slot,yaw,pitch)| Branch { slot, yaw, pitch, length: *len } )
};

// calling the parser
branch(&(1 as u8)).parse("3d2");
```

But that results in this error:

```
type of expression contains references that are not valid during the expression: `combine::combinator::Map<combine::combinator::Map<(combine::combinator::Map<combine::regex::Find<&regex::Regex, &str>, [closure@src\lsystem.rs:26:37: 26:70]>, combine::combinator::Map<combine::regex::Find<&regex::Regex, &str>, [closure@src\lsystem.rs:26:37: 26:70]>, combine::combinator::Map<combine::regex::Find<&regex::Regex, &str>, [closure@src\lsystem.rs:26:37: 26:70]>, combine::combinator::Map<combine::regex::Find<&regex::Regex, &str>, [closure@src\lsystem.rs:26:37: 26:70]>), [closure@src\lsystem.rs:30:19: 30:65]>, [closure@src\lsystem.rs:31:19: 31:80 length:&&u8]>`
```

I have no idea what this error is about. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In your first example, `length: u8` means that there is no lifetime (it's copied every time), and if there's no lifetime for this the error is elsewhere...

Comment: it's odd that the compiler complains about `length` not living long enough then. The line of that error is on the line `.map( |(slot,yaw,pitch)| Branch { slot, yaw, pitch, length } )`.

If length is only being copied why would it complain that it doesn't live long enough?

Comment: Can you edit in the complete Error?

Comment: And a [MCVE]? Without it, any answer has to put in *a lot* of effort to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it:

```
let hex_re = Regex:new(r"[0-9a-fA-F]").unwrap();
let hex = || find(&hex_re).map(|s| u8::from_str_radix(s, 16));
let branch = |length: u8| {
    (hex(), hex(), hex())
        .map( |t| (t.0.unwrap(), t.1.unwrap(), t.2.unwrap()) )
        .map( move |(slot,yaw,pitch)| Branch { slot, yaw, pitch, length } )
}
```

placing move on the second .map works.